# How do I express in JQuery all class but not this one?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to disable right click on the page in general but on each image has a custom jquery dialog. Now the img id is passed to the event so while the menu is the same it will give different results per image.

so I want to bind my generic context menu for non images for all except img class="image"...

so how do I express $(!.image)  ???

**EDIT**
I looked up the not function. I am using it like this:  However I still get general help  even on photos.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('*').not('.public-photo').bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
      $("div.custom-menu").hide();
            event.preventDefault();
            $("<div class='custom-menu'>General Help</div>")
                .appendTo("body")
                .css({top: event.pageY + "px", left: event.pageX + "px"});
        });
        $('*').not(".public-photo").bind("click", function (event) {
             $("div.custom-menu").hide();
        });
 });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: I don't recommend disabling right-click and displaying messages on images. If you have copyright content you don't want accessible for download, don't make it accessible on the web.

Comment: hi it is not for protecting the web content. I want to use it as a help feature for users. Showing my custom jQuery dialog

Answer (score 1):

To get every element excluding images, try this:

```
$('*:not(.image)').dialog({
    // dialog setup...
});
```

Or alternatively:

```
$('*').not('.image')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.yourSelector').not('.image')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector, like this:

```
$(':not(.image)')
```

Or the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method like this:

```
$('<your container>').not('.image')
```

Answer (score 0):

for all except img class image :

using css not pseudo selector :

```
$('*:not(img.image)')
```

using jquery not method

```
$('*').not('img.image')
```